# How to rewrite this "async for loop" using "map"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, higher-order-functions

I am trying to rewrite this async loop using map but I can't achieve the desired result

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const loop = async() => {
  for (const number of numbers) {
    console.log(number);
    await wait(500);
  }
};
loop();
```

But when I try:

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const loop = async() => {
  numbers.map(async(number) => {
    console.log(number);
    await 500;
  });
};
loop();
```

It gives sync behavior!

Can you tell me where is the mistake please?

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` doesn't `await` the passed function. You'd notice you get an array of `Promise`s, if you didn't abuse it for iteration.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it gives sync behavior*"?

Comment: I would assume he means numbers don't show with the delay of 500ms one after another.

Comment: It's not possible to rewrite it using `map`. Using `map` is not rewriting but completely changing the behavior form sequentially waiting to waiting in parallel. If you want to rewrite it you need to write a recursive function.

Comment: @slebetman `reduce` can also do it. If *really* needed, I'd opt for that rather than recursion. But I'm not sure when I'd use it over a normal loop.

Comment: @VLAZ How? Reduce works exactly like map in that it accepts a callback and within that callback you cannot await properly (sequentially). If you say reduce can do it then map also can. In which case feel free to write that as an answer (map that is) because that's exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @slebetman `arr.reduce((p, x) => p.then( x => console.log(x) ).then( () => wait(500) ), Promise.resolve())` - just reduce them into a promise chain. Then it's going to be sequential.

Comment: Here's an equivalent using for-loop
`const wait = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const loop = () => {
    let promise = Promise.resolve();
    for (const number of numbers) {
        promise = promise.then(() => {
            console.log(number);
            return wait(500);
        });
    }
};
loop();`